# Map of highway fuel stops in Germany

Tags: germany, planning, automobiles, maps

I'm looking for a map of highway fuel stops in Germany. I've seen the what-looks-like official site [Tank and Rast](http://tank.rast.de/en/), but they are very obviously outdated (at least by 10 years, looking at the missing pieces of A6).

I'm planning a long journey and I'd like to know where to stop in advance. I'd be also happy with having a good route planner (such as [Viamichelin.com](http://www.viamichelin.com/)) but one that would offer the fuel stops to be shown as well.

Comment: Fuel stops are numerous here. There are multiple large companies, as well as many privately owned ones. You do not really need to plan ahead for the fuel stops.

Comment: The "Raststätten" operated by Tank&Rast are only part of the fuel stops. There are also at least as many "Autohöfe", which are service areas directly next to an exit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[maps.adac.de](http://maps.adac.de/) has this feature. The page appears to be German only, but it shouldn't be too difficult to use. The first input box on the left is your starting point, the one below it your destination. Then click on "Weitere auswählen (0/38)" and check the box next to "Tankstellen & Spritpreise".
Next click "Weiter" and or "Route berechnen" and after some calculation time you'll see the fuel stops along your route.

That being said: fuel stops on the Autobahn are barely ever more than 60 km apart and before you drive past one, you can see the distance to the next one on the sign. So I wouldn't worry about them in advance.

Comment: yes, the fact that in central Europe you always know in how many kilometers the next stop is can't be stressed enough. 
I never inform myself before and I may skip several stops until I find one that works with my benefits card. 
Of course, you have to start thinking before you start using the fuel reserve. 

The only way to be in trouble is if there's a fuel stop strike. And a map won't help you around that.

Answer (score 4):

When I was stationed over there in the early 2000's, you could buy a map from Esso that had all their other stations located on the map. If you're looking for a non-tech solution to make sure you can get fuel, this is one option.

Answer (score 3):

When I traveled to Germany a few years ago (US citizen) I realized that my cell phone plan wouldn't have data service over there, and as such, Google maps would be useless. I looked around for a GPS app that allowed you to pre-load maps, and eventually decided on CoPilot GPS (I have no association with the app, just a satisfied user.)

You do need to pay for maps, but you get the first one for free, to let you see if you even like the app. I chose the pack with Germany (which includes Austria, Switzerland, and Liechtenstein, which is nice.) I found the maps to be as accurate as could be expected, and were very helpful for getting around in a country I'd never been to before (and where my language was rather rusty!)

If you have a smart phone with GPS, I cannot suggest it enough. It should certainly help you find your way, without having to worry about roaming charges or foreign data plans. Even if you don't take it with you, maybe their maps will be updated enough to help you plan in advance.

Comment: Nokia Here & Drive are free and allow map download too.

Comment: @Formagella Thanks, I've been wondering what other options there are out there. May try that one out in the future to see if I like it better.